# how to calculate php differential equation

Tags: php

I have a calculation in php like

$outpout = 1.056^(365/10)

But it not calculating in right manner

you can try it like $outpout = (3^3);

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In PHP, `^` is an XOR [bitwise operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php), not an exponential operator

Answer (score 0):

> As of PHP 5.6.0 we have `**` operator

If you need 3^3

You can do `$x = 3 ** 3 ;`

> If you are using older version, use

`$x = pow(3, 3) ;`

In both cases `$x` will be `27`

Source: [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php)